# Ytake Laravel Aspect with Lumen 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, aop, lumen, aspect

I am using Lumen 5.6. When I run any commands or access any functions through Postman I got this error:

```
Class 'App\Providers\AnnotationConfiguration' not found
```

When I added this use Ytake\LaravelAspect\AnnotationConfiguration; in AspectServiceProvider.php, the above issue resolved but now I am getting this error.

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Ytake\LaravelAspect\AnnotationConfiguration::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\Projects\cs415_api\app\Providers\AspectServiceProvider.php on line 22
```

I suspect that the following line in AspectServiceProvider returns null.

```
$app['config']->get('ytake-laravel-aop.annotation')
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved here:

https://github.com/ytake/Laravel-Aspect/issues/53